# how to get row index from mysql result in codeignitier when search by id or code

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the data :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [code] => 12345
            [name] => Aaron
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [code] => 16784
            [name] => Bryan
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 35
            [code] => 32467
            [name] => Charlie
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 25
            [code] => 44513
            [name] => Denise
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 44
            [code] => 15774
            [name] => Michael
        )
)
```

In my model i create function :

```
private function getPosition($field_search, $field_value){ // ID or code        
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->order_by('name','asc');
    $result = $this->db->get()->result();
    $pos = array_search($field_value, array_column($result, $field_search));

    return ($pos !==false ? $pos : -1);
}
```

if i want to get row index of "32467", i just call

```
$pos = $this->getPosition('code', '32467');
```

then i got the row index is "2",
but i wonder, how to get row index if the query is :

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from($this->table);
$this->db->where('code', '32467');
$this->db->order_by('name','asc');
$result = $this->db->get()->result();
```

litte correction in my question,
i mean, if we index in database where code = "32467", we've got index is "2", 
how to get return if index is "2"

thanks for your help...

Comment: With the same code?

Comment: @u_mulder, i correct my question, i mean, if we index in database where code = "32467", we've got index is "2", how to get return if index is "2"

Comment: `2` is not an index in database. It is index in array and it is not related to database in any way.

Comment: @Saddler you need array index key?

Comment: @u_mulder, ah, i think CI or PHP have a script/function could related to database which is return of the index :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar, yes i need array index which is related with index in database

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

    $userdb= Array
    (
        "0" => Array(
                'id' => "12",
                'code' => "12345",
                'name' => 'Aaron'
            ),

        "1" => Array
            (
                "id" => "5",
                "code" => "16784",
                "name" => "Bryan"
            ),
        "2" => Array
            (
                "id" => "35",
                "code" => "32467",
                "name" => "Charlie"
            ),
        "3" => Array
            (
                "id" => "25",
                "code" => "44513",
                "name" => "Denise"
            ),
        "4" => Array
            (
                "id" => "44",
                "code" => "15774",
                "name" => "Michael"
            ),
    );

    $key = array_search(32467, array_column($userdb, 'code'));

    echo ("The key is: ".$key);

private function getPosition($field_search, $field_value){ // ID or code        
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->order_by('name','asc');
    $result = $this->db->get()->result();
    $key = array_search($field_value, array_column($result, $field_search));
    return $key;
}
    ?>
```